# How do I parse and format this data properly?

Tags: c++

I am doing an assignment that requires us to simply read data from a entered text file (the text file cannot be hard coded into the program), and then extract the data, and print it out into a vertical histogram denoting the frequency of each number using stars. I believe I have the program complete except I cannot get the call function I designed to parse the data to actually parse it! Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong within my code? I really appreciate any help. To clarify the data set is assumed to always be 21 columns and 2 rows, arranged vertically.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void OpenFile(ifstream&);
void ParseFileLines(ifstream&, int*, int*);
void CloseFile(ifstream&);
void DrawGraphs(int*, int*);

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    int speed[21];
    int incline[21];

    OpenFile(inFile);
    ParseFileLines(inFile, incline, speed);
    CloseFile(inFile);
    DrawGraphs(speed, incline);
}

void DrawGraphs(int * speed, int * incline)
{
    cout << "SPEED GRAPHIC:" << endl;
    cout << "   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10" << endl;
    cout << "---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
    {
        cout << string(speed[i] + 3, '*');
    }

    cout << "INCLINE GRAPHIC:" << endl;
    cout << "   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10" << endl;
    cout << "---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
    {
        cout << string(incline[i] + 3, '*') <<endl; 
    }
}

void CloseFile(ifstream & file)
{
    file.clear();
    file.close();
}

void ParseFileLines(ifstream & file, int * speed, int * incline)
{
    {
        char line[3];
        int i = 0;
        while (!file.eof())
        {
            file.getline(line, 3, ' ');
            speed[i] = line[0];
            incline[i] = line[2];
            i++;
        }
    }
}

void OpenFile(ifstream& file)
{
    string a;

    cout << "Enter the filename" << endl;
    getline(cin, a);
    file.open((a.c_str()));

    while (!file.good())
    {
        file.clear();
        cout << "File failed to open" << endl;
        cout << "Please re-enter the pathway" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        file.open(a.c_str());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ifsteam.read (buffer, 20);
```

Will read 20 characters into a buffer. That should get you going.

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply, where would I put that into my code? Is ifsteam.read a call function?

Comment: cin is an ifstream. So is infile. I'm not trying to be obtuse, just let you learn while solving the problem.

Comment: gah I don't know I don't know, now I just get this error, First-chance exception at 0x75A8C41F in Workout.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x003BE404.
Unhandled exception at 0x75A8C41F in Workout.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x003BE404.

Comment: What format is the input file in? Comma-delimited list? Binary?

Comment: I do not know how to make a list in this comment box but the data in the .txt file is 2 vertical columns with two numbers per every row. 21 rows total.

Comment: Something must separate the values. Newline for rows but what for columns? Space? Tab? Vertical bar?

Comment: oh a space separates each number. So my code is good but I am allocating the memory incorrectly somewhere?

Comment: Remember that getline appends a zero character after reading so a buffer for 3 characters needs to be 4 long to accommodate it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a file to open.

You can either do it in the constructor `ifstream inFile("myFile", mode);` [More about ifstream here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/)

Or you can use the open() method which works on the same principle: `inFile.open("myFile", mode); [More information about open here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/).

Both links explain what to put in mode in case you're not sure.

Comment: but if I specify the files name is that considered "hard coding" the file into the program?

Comment: No, "hard coded" means to have the actual text content in your code, say in an `std::string` which you would then parse. You need to specify what file you're opening otherwise it won't work. If you don't want to rely on a specific file name, I would suggest adding a `std::cin` code somewhere to ask the user for the file name.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification, I am working on trying to fix it now.